# Saving records in json appending them and parsing

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to build with GSON something like database. I want to store records of same object, and be able to append new records anytime. Also, I'm trying to build parser which will take all objects from json to an ArrayList. How am i able to do this? Currently I wrote something like this:

```
public void addRecord(Record record) throws IOException {

    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter("/file.json", true));

    writer.setIndent(" ");
    gson.toJson(record, Record.class, writer);
    writer.close();
}
```

But intelliJ tells me that JSON standard allows only one top-level value. How to avoid it? As i understand, file should contain only one list and i should append new objects to it, but I don't know how. Also, how to parse them to an ArrayList?

Comment: So basically you want to store a list of `Records`? .

Comment: @NiVeR exactly, and return them

Comment: I will write you an example in some minutes.

Answer (score 1):

> But intelliJ tells me that JSON standard allows only one top-level value.

Yes.
What you implemented is concatenated JSON (see [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming)).
You can still use it, but your record files won't be parsed by JSON-compliant tools.
If you don't want to use "raw" JSON streams, you can implement JSON array-based streams.
This requires some work, but it will let you produce and consume valid JSON documents.

```java
final class JsonStreams {

    private JsonStreams() {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    static void copy(final JsonReader reader, final JsonWriter writer)
            throws IOException {
        int level = 0;
        loop:
        for ( JsonToken token = reader.peek(); token != null; token = reader.peek() ) {
            switch ( token ) {
            case BEGIN_ARRAY:
                reader.beginArray();
                writer.beginArray();
                ++level;
                break;
            case END_ARRAY:
                reader.endArray();
                writer.endArray();
                if ( --level == 0 ) {
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case BEGIN_OBJECT:
                reader.beginObject();
                writer.beginObject();
                ++level;
                break;
            case END_OBJECT:
                reader.endObject();
                writer.endObject();
                if ( --level == 0 ) {
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case NAME:
                final String name = reader.nextName();
                writer.name(name);
                break;
            case STRING:
                final String s = reader.nextString();
                writer.value(s);
                break;
            case NUMBER:
                final Number n = new BigDecimal(reader.nextString());
                writer.value(n);
                break;
            case BOOLEAN:
                final boolean b = reader.nextBoolean();
                writer.value(b);
                break;
            case NULL:
                reader.nextNull();
                writer.nullValue();
                break;
            case END_DOCUMENT:
                break loop;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError(token);
            }
        }
    }

    static void appendToArray(final JsonReader jsonReader, final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final Consumer<? super JsonWriter> consumer)
            throws IOException {
        // Making JsonReader set to END_DOCUMENT if there is a blank/whitespace document
        try {
            jsonReader.hasNext();
        } catch ( final EOFException ignored ) {
        }
        // Checking the outer-most JSON token
        final JsonToken beginJsonToken = jsonReader.peek();
        switch ( beginJsonToken ) {
        // If it's a blank/whitespace document, then just write a single row
        case END_DOCUMENT:
            jsonWriter.beginArray();
            consumer.accept(jsonWriter);
            jsonWriter.endArray();
            break;
        // If the document starts with [, then unroll all its values
        case BEGIN_ARRAY:
            jsonReader.beginArray();
            jsonWriter.beginArray();
            final JsonToken endJsonToken = jsonReader.peek();
            if ( endJsonToken != JsonToken.END_ARRAY ) {
                // Copy all existing values
                while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
                    final JsonToken rowJsonToken = jsonReader.peek();
                    switch ( rowJsonToken ) {
                    case BEGIN_ARRAY:
                    case BEGIN_OBJECT:
                    case STRING:
                    case NUMBER:
                    case BOOLEAN:
                    case NULL:
                        copy(jsonReader, jsonWriter);
                        break;
                    // The rest of tokens must never happen because we copy values
                    case END_ARRAY:
                    case END_OBJECT:
                    case NAME:
                    case END_DOCUMENT:
                    default:
                        throw new AssertionError(rowJsonToken);
                    }
                }
            }
            consumer.accept(jsonWriter);
            // End the document with ]
            jsonReader.endArray();
            jsonWriter.endArray();
            break;
        default:
            throw new JsonParseException("Unexpected outer token: " + beginJsonToken);
        }
    }

}
```

```java
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    final Iterable<String> resourceNames = ImmutableList.of("1-blank.json", "2-empty.json", "3-some.json");
    for ( final String resourceName : resourceNames ) {
        try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = Resources.getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q50418170.class, resourceName) ) {
            final Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            final JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(writer);
            JsonStreams.appendToArray(jsonReader, jsonWriter, jw -> {
                gson.toJson(fooBar(1, 2), jw);
                gson.toJson(fooBar(3, 4), jw);
                gson.toJson(fooBar(5, 6), jw);
            });
            System.out.println(writer);
        }
    }
}

private static JsonElement fooBar(final int foo, final int bar) {
    final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.add("foo", new JsonPrimitive(foo));
    jsonObject.add("bar", new JsonPrimitive(bar));
    return jsonObject;
}
```

The test documents above are as follows:

#### 1-blank.json

*<no content; zero-length file>*

#### 2-empty.json

```js
[
]
```

#### 3-some.json

This document is formatted by intention, but I would store JSON documents minified (hence, I wouldn't use `setIndent`).

```js
[
    {
        "foo": 0,
        "bar": 0,
        "baz": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
]
```

The test for the above documents would produce the following output

```js
[{"foo":1,"bar":2},{"foo":3,"bar":4},{"foo":5,"bar":6}]
[{"foo":1,"bar":2},{"foo":3,"bar":4},{"foo":5,"bar":6}]
[{"foo":0,"bar":0,"baz":[1,2,3]},{"foo":1,"bar":2},{"foo":3,"bar":4},{"foo":5,"bar":6}]
```